What should we do with the [time-sensitive] tag?
I recently came across the time-sensitive tag, which seems to be used pretty haphazardly across a bunch of questions dealing with various aspects of time-related cryptography (e.g. time-lock puzzles, cryptoperiods, secure time synchronization), presumably because it happens to be one of the few tags we have with "time" in its name and because it looked generic enough and had no tag wiki.
I just added a quick tag wiki summary for it, essentially codifying the existing haphazard usage pattern, but I'm not really happy about that, so I'd like a second opinion on what to do with it:

Leave the scope broad, rename the tag to just time to reflect the scope.
Remove it from everything but questions dealing with time-lock puzzles (and maybe long-term encryption / cryptoperiods), edit tag wiki to reflect narrowed scope.  May need some new tags to replace it on the edited questions.
Meh, it's good enough like this, just leave it as it is.


Also, what about the other existing tag with "time" (not prefixed with "one-") in its name, timestamping?  It too needs a tag wiki.  Should these two tags have non-overlapping scopes, or should one perhaps subsume the other?

Edit: Since the consensus seems to be to split / eliminate the tag, let me list the questions currently tagged with it and try to figure out how they should be tagged:

Time Capsule cryptography?
What is the progress on the MIT LCS35 Time Capsule Crypto-Puzzle?
These are both about time-lock puzzles.  We could make a new tag for them (e.g. timed-release), or maybe retag them under the existing proof-of-work tag.
How does one calculate the cryptoperiod?
This one's also kind of related, given that it's about how long a cipher may be assumed to remain secure.  Still, we could just remove the tag from it and leave it only tagged with standards. I think I was the one who tagged it in the first place, anyway.
Is there an algorithm or hardware that can sign/verify natural time?
Any problems with this secure time synchronization scheme?
The first question above looks like it should be retagged with timestamping.  The second (which, incidentally, was the one that prompted this meta question) could maybe also fit under timestamping in a loose sense.
Is it possible to make time-locked encrytion algorithm?
This one's basically about time-lapse cryptography, sensu Rabin & Thorpe, which might make a decent tag in itself.  Or if we make a timed-release tag for the first two questions above, we could put this one under it too.
Self-expiring symmetric keys, or: cryptography in absence of secure deletion
This one's the oddball.  Dunno what to do with it.  Maybe just remove the tag?


I personally think #2 is the best option.

Thinking more about this issue, I think you're dead-on in your comments. I agree with the recommendation to replace [tag:time-sensitive] with [tag:proof-of-work] for questions 1 and 2, since that's the gist of those two. Further, the "cryptoperiod" question is sort of an odd one, and I think removing [tag:time-sensitive] but leaving [tag:standards] is a good idea (after all, a "cryptoperiod" is pretty much a standards-related thing entirely, especially if the NIST was the entity who defined it ...). [...]

[...] The [tag:timestamping] tag is a bit trickier. I agree the first question you presented should be tagged with it, but I'm not sure the second fits. We could perhaps shoehorn it into [tag:timestamping], yes, but I don't think that works well. Not sure what to do there. The next question ("time-locked") is another question that is unique enough that I'm not sure we can find a good tag for it, and the last question is similar in nature (in my opinion). I guess my question is, what do we do with (good) questions that have unique subject matter, unlikely to be repeated?

Here's my proposal how to re-tag the questions you listed.  In each case, replace the tag time-sensitive with....

Time Capsule cryptography?
either timed-release (if we create it), or encryption (since this question is about maintaining confidentiality for a set of time)
What is the progress on the MIT LCS35 Time Capsule Crypto-Puzzle?
same as before.
How does one calculate the cryptoperiod?
nothing.  the remaining tags, standards and implementation are good.
Is there an algorithm or hardware that can sign/verify natural time?
this one is fine as is (with timestamping)
Any problems with this secure time synchronization scheme?
nothing.  The existing tag, protocol-design, is fine.  timestamping does not look right here, since this is not about timestamping (not even close).
Is it possible to make time-locked encrytion algorithm?
either encryption and/or protocol-design; or timed-release if we add it.
Self-expiring symmetric keys, or: cryptography in absence of secure deletion
forward-secrecy, keys, and key-rotation.

In all cases, the existing other tags should be left in place.
At least, that's my proposal.

...aaand it's done. I ended up creating the [tag:timed-release] tag (which currently lacks a proper tag wiki, it only has an excerpt) and mostly followed the suggestions here. Thanks!

I think time-sensitive is a poor choice for a tag name.  It is not descriptive: it's not clear what it would refer to.  To me, "time-sensitive" makes me think of something that is urgent or has a short deadline.
I suggest removing time-sensitive from everything.  Let's kill it.
We can use timestamping for timestamping-related questions.  For other questions, either we go without a special tag -- or we invent one that is more suitable.  But for now, deleting time-sensitive seems like the right first step.  I don't feel a burning need to have a specific replacement in every case before deleting time-sensitive, given that we're only talking about a few questions.

I think you're right, "time-sensitive" is a bad tag name anyway.  I've listed the seven questions currently tagged with it above, along with some ideas on what to do with them.  If nobody has any better ideas, I think I'll start retagging them gradually, probably starting with the ones that should just be moved under [tag:timestamping].
